# windows 10 stop prompt enable firewall

Tags: windows-10

In a domain network I had to disable the firewall.

Now windows 10 is prompting me randomly to enable the firewall.

If I click on the message the firewall gets re-enabled.

Is there a way to disable this prompt?

Comment: Why why why did you disable the firewall instead of using group policy to configure the necessary exceptions?

Comment: Because I've been ordered to do so. I never said I liked doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a windows security feature and as such, that message can't be disabled, it will eventually prompt or pop-up sometimes.